# style sheet and iframes

Tags: css, wordpress, iframe, stylesheet

I currently have an existing iframe in my WP site.

Now, I would like to add an external website using a second iframe but I needed to shrink the website within the iframe so I did it by using an style sheet. But when I preview my page, the style sheet had also scaled my other iframe, which I did not want to happen.

I don't have much experience coding but any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What code have you tried? Post it

Comment: @mlegg:

<html>
<body>
<style>
iframe {
  -moz-transform: scale(0.6, 0.6); 
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.75, 0.6); 
  -o-transform: scale(0.6, 0.6);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.6, 0.6);
  transform: scale(0.6, 0.6); 
  -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -o-transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  transform-origin: top left;
}
</style>
<iframe style="border:none; width:1024px;height:700px;overflow-y:hidden;" seamless src="http://www.bbc.com/news">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>